# Mma 11.1.1 does not recognize GPU

Tags: mac-os-x, neural-networks, cudalink, gpu

The newest version of Mma 11.1.1 advertises

> "Re-enabled GPU support for neural networks for Mac."

But when I install on an Apple MacBook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M GPU, and I do:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
```

followed by

```
CUDAQ[]
```

I get

```
False
```

Does Wolfram not support this GPU?

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: Version OSX 10.12.4

Comment: I have same GPU/OS/mathematica and I get True. Check that your CUDA works, I've setup CUDA for other applications beforehand. Note though that 750M is quite slow, I get no speed benefit from using GPU implementation for neural net training

Comment: By the way, the neural network functionality is completely independent of `CUDALink`.

Comment: I am not actually using it for neural networks. I just want to do some image processing a little faster.

Comment: I'm not aware of the x.x.1 update for Mathematica 11.  Is it already released?

Comment: As Ilian said, CUDALink and NetTrain's GPU support are entirely different and unrelated things.  CUDALink works fine for me on the same hardware (2014 MacBook Pro) with 11.1.0 (but NetTrain does not—I do not yet have 11.1.1).  Did you install CUDA on your computer before trying this?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Maybe your CPU is much powerful than mine, but I'm getting a 10X speedup in GPU for MNIST examples in the documentation on my macbook pro with 750M.

Comment: I actually didn't test Mathematica, only TensorFlow. Using TensorFlow, there's almost no speed-up using LeNet5 on my MacBook 2014 by moving ops to the GPU. I would expect that Mathematica CPU implementation of network is bad somehow if GPU is faster